# Permission to schedule posts on Facebook wall using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to schedule a post on a Facebook wall, but I just get an error like 'you do not have permission to schedule posts'.

What permissions do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Posts can only be scheduled on Facebook Pages. There are a few steps:

- Get the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens) from the user.
- Make sure the user has at least the [`CREATE_CONTENT` role](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#roles).
- [Publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing#publish) to `/<page_id>/feed?published=false&scheduled_publish_time=<unix_time>`